# WCF: Should I store ServiceClient or create for each call?

Tags: .net, wcf, service, soa

I have service: UserService and Client: UserServiceClient.

Should I store UserServiceClient in class and use this instance for each call?

Or maybe better create this object before each call(or calls, but in one place) ?

Comment: I think you should create the object each time because whenever an exception would be returned from the service, Channel becomes faulty and then you can not use that channel in further communication.

Comment: Thanks it' s good reason.